# Split A Long String Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, sidekiq

I'm working on retrieving scheduled newsletter on Sidekiq. The details such subject, created at and scheduled at, are suppose to be displayed on the frontend as a notification to the admin. I have been able to go as further as below. How do I breakdown this string even more in order to display only the subject, created at, and scheduled at at the frontend ??

String :

```
"---\n- !ruby/class 'Subscriber'\n- :send_in_batch_now!\n- - !ruby/hash:NewsletterOption\n    welcome_message: ''\n    body_message: ''\n    sender_id: 1\n    sender_name: 8Share Malaysia\n    from_email: malaysia@8share.com\n    country_code: my\n    test: false\n    subject: testnewsletter1\n    campaign_ids:\n    - '3'\n    scheduled: true\n    scheduled_at: 2015-05-28 08:45:00.000000000 Z\n    errors: []\n    category: version2/d/my/2015/05/26/jkhkjh\n"
```

Comment: Do `YAML.load(string)`.. you have a YAML file it seems..

Comment: I'm trying to extract a scheduled newsletter from Sidekiq. i got this string after running 
$ r= Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
$jobs = r.map {|re| re.args[0]}

output : - 
["---\n- !ruby/class 'Subscriber'\n- :send_in_batch_now!\n- - !ruby/hash:NewsletterOption\n    welcome_message: ''\n    body_message: ''\n    sender_id: 1\n    sender_name: 8Share Malaysia\n    from_email: malaysia@8share.com\n    country_code: my\n    test: false\n    subject: jkhkjh\n    campaign_ids:\n    - '3'\n    scheduled: true\n    scheduled_at: 2015-05-28 08:45:00.000000000 Z\n    errors: []\n  ]

Comment: im getting this error : TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String

Comment: Can you show how do you schedule this task? It seems you are trying  to pass model via `perform_async` which is not the best approach. Pass model id instead and load model from the database within your worker instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
require 'yaml'
result = YAML.load(string)
puts result
```

if you want load from file

```
require 'yaml'
result = YAML.load_file(file.yml)
puts result
```